# IP settings of cassandra across data centers

Tags: cassandra

We need to deploy cassandra clusters acorss 2 data centers with 6 nodes each. Each data center has just 2 nodes owning public IP to communicate with other data center. Can I set 6 nodes in each data center with private IPs for internal communication and 2 nodes with public IPs for public communication?

If so, how to configure the cassandra?

If not, where can I modify the cassandra sources to enable it?

In answer, [IP address resolution in Cassandra MultiDC setup](https://serverfault.com/questions/263064/ip-address-resolution-in-cassandra-multidc-setup). It says that Cassandra assumes each node can communicate directly with each other node. VPN should be adopted. However, in our team, we really worry about the availability of VPN.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but for anyone else looking at this one option is to assign all nodes public IP's this not only increases your throughput overall but also is the preferred configuration for this type of a setup. Simply encrypt the connections with TLS and you're good to go.